# Are people aware of who Naruto's parents are?

Tags: naruto

Every villager in Konoha is aware that Naruto has the Kyuubi sealed inside of him.

Is anyone in the village or elsewhere (other than Kakashi and Jiraiya, that I remember knew) aware that he is the son of Minato and Kushina?
My main doubt being: **do they know that he is the son of the Fourth Hokage**?

Comment: some people in the village or were in the village already knew who his parents were like (3rd hokage , Kakashi sensei , and the people who dicided Naruto's last name.) thoughs are people who already new .... but seriously how could everybody not know naruto looks just like the 4th and if people new who the 4th hokage married they would know instantly that naruto was minato's son (4th hokage's son)

Comment: retroactive continuity

Comment: extension of the question: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47895/why-didnt-the-entire-village-know-naruto-was-minatos-son/47936#47936

Comment: I think they are protecting Minatos' legacy by not naming naruto after Minato.

Answer (score 12):

Most of them didn't know. It was a secret to protect Naruto. Just a few people knew it. I found proof on [this](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki#cite_note-10) site:

> Suddenly orphaned, Naruto was left to grow up knowing nothing of his parents, receiving only his mother's last name because the Third Hokage thought that it was best that nobody knew that he was related to the Fourth Hokage.

They found it here: Naruto chapter 440, page 5

Answer (score 3):

> You forgot the third Hokage (and some other Anbu's).

IMO they aren't.
After all you can see how everyone who knew that info treated him entirely different from the rest.

**Edit:** As Madara said,
It really was TABOO not to talk about it in the village (About the demon inside Naruto etc).
Nevertheless, I do not think it was so complicated inform those who need to know that.

Comment: I second this. Remember that entire ordeal with Neji, during the chuunin exams, talking about how "You're born a loser", and such things? I have always wondered how that would've played out if Neji knew Naruto was the son of the most legendary ninja to have ever existed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. After their names were revealed, it seems as if "suddenly" everyone knew about it. Even Gai, and even the Raikage mentioned his parents without them being mentioned earlier.

That leads me to believe that people knew, and it was part of the taboo not to speak of it (or Kishimoto still hadn't thought about it then :D)

Comment: `Raikage mentioned his parents?` when and where??

Comment: ya he mentions .. gotta link :) http://www.mangareader.net/naruto/544/4

Comment: I think some people knew like gai and kakashi but that some just saw the resemblance, because when he's 16 he really looks like a younger version of his dad. Next to that I think that every kage who was in an alliance with konoha would have know about the fourth hokage and his son

Answer (score 1):

Obviously they don't. He was celebrated after defeating Pain, not because he's the Fourth's son, but rather because he became the hero of the village.
Btw, I think Naruto is happier to be acknowledged as a hero because of his acts and not because he's the son of a former Hokage. The only persons that knew about the truth were: Jiraiya, Sarutobi, maybe Kakashi (we saw a lot of time that Kakashi imagines he's teacher and mentor in Naruto, maybe he realized the relationship, but he didn't know that from the beginning), and a few ANBU members who were at that place when Naruto was born.

Answer (score 0):

Kakashi would have been one of the few who knew because one of his assignments as ANBU was to be a secret body guard for Minato's wife while she was pregnant. As for why people who knew who Minato married didnt put two and two together when suddenly this boy who looks oddly similar to the fourth ended up being born in their village and happend to be the one cursed to carry the burden of the price that was paid to save the village.